# javafx black screen bug borderpane.setCenter

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I would like to confirm if other people have the same problem with javafx, or if someone knows a solution for this.

**The problem:**

Black borderPane when a pane of the borderPane is changed and the application is minimized.

**Reproduce the problem:**

1. Create a borderPane and set any pane in the center.
2. When the application is minimized change the center panel.
3. Un minimize the application.
4. The borderPane appear black.

The following code is a working example of the problema.

Java code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("MainPain.fxml"));
            BorderPane page = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(page,400,400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader();
            loader2.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Pane1.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page2 = loader2.load();

            FXMLLoader loader3 = new FXMLLoader();
            loader3.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Pane2.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page3 = loader3.load();

            page.setCenter(page2);

            primaryStage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                   page.setCenter(page3);
                }
            });

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML codes:

BorderPanel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Panel 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="216.0" layoutY="172.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Pane1" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Panel 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>



<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="240.0" layoutY="205.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Pane2" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The windows is repainted if a hover event is detected, in this example by passin over the menu. This does not change the fact that the pane is black when the application is un minimized.

There was a bug in 2014 that make pane go black when minimized and un minimized from the windows bar. But this is not the case, it only happen when the pane is changed when the application is minimized.

Environment:
Windows 7 64
Java version: 1.8.0_121
Java(TM) Se Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM(build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
JavaFX Scene Builder 8.3.0